# breadcrumb's items in bootstrap-vue project

Tags: vue.js, breadcrumbs, bootstrap-vue

In my vue/cli 4/vuex / bootstrap-vue project app I want to add
breadcrumbs, as I read here :
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/breadcrumb/

and I wander how can I make breadcrumb's items for any page, as breadcrumbs are different for any page?

I have vauge idea as in src/main.js I have :

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  bus.$emit('page_changed', from, to)
})
```

and in container src/App.vue I have :

```
bus.$on('page_changed', (from, to) => {

}) // bus.$on('page_changed', (from, to) => {
```

I suppose that in src/App I can have array of items for any pages of the system
and in page_changed array depending on current page(tp parameter of page_changed event)
set to items of breadcrumbs. I am not sure will it work ?

Any ideas?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vuex": "^3.1.2"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Inspect `this.$route` to get the current path of the route, split it on `/`  (e.g. `this.$router.path.split('/')`) and then use that resulting array to generate your breadcrumbs.

Comment: Do you mean to make it in page_changed event ?

Comment: `this.$route` is reactive, so you don't need to tie it to an event at all.